# This query gives repetitive record, What is the wrong in this query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

This is the query which gives repeated result:

```
SELECT a.applicant_particular_id, a.name, a.father_name, a.quota_id, 
c.hafiz_quran_marks, b.form_status 
FROM applicant_particular a,admission_choices b, academic_background c 
WHERE b.applicant_particular_id=a.applicant_particular_id 
   AND c.applicant_particular_id=a.applicant_particular_id 
   AND a.quota_id='18'
   AND b.form_status='RECEIVED'
```

This is the first table "applicant_particular"

[image: The red highlighted rows are repeating and hafiz_quran_marks is showing with all rows]

This is the first table "applicant_particular"

```
   applicant_particular_id   |   name   |   father_name   |    quota_id


             1                   John        Micheal             18
             2                   khan        ali                 19
```

This is the second table "admission_choices"

```
   choice_id   |   form_status   |   applicant_particular_id   |    program_id


           1          PENDING               2                       19
           2          RECEIVED              1                       18
```

This is the third table "academic_background"

```
   background_id   |   hafiz_marks   |   applicant_particular_id   


           1             20                  2     
           2             30                  1
```

Comment: can you use `distinct` with this ?. Also try using `joins` for referring multiple tables. like `Select distinct a.applicant_particular_id ......`

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read, and easier to convert to outer join (if needed.)

Comment: @stack i will use the `distinct` but the `hafiz_marks` column is showing with each and every row. it should be use with its own related row I don't know why?

Comment: @jarlh Indeed, but that hasn't been considered good practice for more than 10 years now

Comment: A good rule of thumb is "don't use comma joins. ever." And see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query?noredirect=1#comment391934_333952

Comment: @BilalSaqib: It seems there might be issue in relation then. You need to figure out which columns needs to be referred for proper result.

Comment: i used the `join` but the result is same

Comment: @stack I referred `applicant_particular_id` in each table, I think relationship is OK

Comment: You should check your data because I believe that causes the duplication. You may have more than 1 record associated with an applicant in the application choices or academic background tables and these may cause multiple records to appear. Moreover, your query and the results on the screenshot do not seem to be in line with each other because on the screenshot I can see records with quota_Id<>18

Comment: @shadow yes you are right  I have more than 1 record associated with an applicant in the application choices and academic background tables just because of my application needs, and this screenshot is the result of by query and I don't know why this quota_id<>18 is showing.

Comment: We do not have enough information to provide you with a solution atm. Pls show sample records that cause the duplication along with some sample data for applicants with non 18 quota id. Pls note that no matter what we do, a view eliminating duplications are likely not to be updatable. Also, this criterion was not even mentioned in the question, so you must not expect any of the answers to take this point into consideration. You should update the question and provide all criteria and actually ask a question. Because atm there is no question in the post.

Answer (score 5):

Try switching to explicit joins, then bash in the distinct for good measure

```
SELECT distinct 
        a.applicant_particular_id, 
        a.name, 
        a.father_name, 
        a.quota_id, 
        c.hafiz_quran_marks, 
        b.form_status 
FROM applicant_particular a
INNER JOIN admission_choices b
  ON b.applicant_particular_id=a.applicant_particular_id 
INNER JOIN academic_background c 
  ON c.applicant_particular_id=a.applicant_particular_id 
WHERE a.quota_id='18'
AND b.form_status='RECEIVED'
```

Comment: If we create a `view` of this query then it `update` , `delete` features are not available because it doesn't contain a unique column, then what will be the solution?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that you have multiple records for foreign key in 2nd and 3rd table,

```
applicant_particular_id   |   name   |   father_name   |    quota_id
         1                   John        Micheal             18
         2                   khan        ali                 19`
```

Table2 have two foreign key for row1

```
choice_id   |   form_status   |   applicant_particular_id   |    program_id
       1          PENDING               1                       19
       2          RECEIVED              1                       18
```

in the above case query will give multiple record for table1#row1 
for solving the duplicate issue you have to add distinct as mention by @JohnHC

Comment: There are 3 records in table2 and 4 records in table3 for 1 row in table1 so I think it gives me 4*3=12 records without using a `distinct` , and when i use `distinct` then as per my need the view can't be updated. So stilll i didn't get solution.